# Scrapy Multiple Spiders executing serially

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy project. I have integrated the spider with selenium webdriver and the code looks something like this.

```
def start(i):
    //do some navigation with selenium webdriver

    return url

class abc(BaseSpider):
    name = '123'
    x = start(5)
    start_urls = [x]
    def parse(self, response):

        // scrape data.


class fgh(BaseSpider):
    name = '456'
    x = start(8)
    start_urls = [x]
    def parse(self, response):

        // scrape data.

.... and so on {20 classes as such}..
```

Now whenever I try `scrapy crawl 456`, it starts executing from the first spider that is '123'. The control is not being transferred to respective spider. I'm new to selenium and scrapy. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was with the `.pyc` files. I deleted it, and now it runs fine.